# Django Python DB Updates

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a django model using mongo engine. In the model which is,

```
class MyMap(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True, primary_key=True,max_length=50,unique=True)
    cars = DictField()
```

If I update the db like so it will over right the first entry made. Is there any option to perform an update to the dictfield without doing it outside of the model ?

```
x = MyMap(name="dave",cars={"ford":"abc"})
x.save()

x = MyMap(name="dave",cars={"mini":"abc"})
x.save()
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason behind `class MyMap(Document)` instead of `class MyMap(models.Model)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update the cars attribute without overwriting the existing information then you could do something like:

```
x = MyMap(name="dave",cars={"ford":"abc"})
x.save()

x.cars.update({"mini":"abc"})
x.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you mean with "outside of the model", but couldn't you just get the document from the db and update it and then save it?

```
doc = MyMap.objects(name="dave").first()
if doc:
    doc.cars = {"mini":"abc"}
    doc.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the object and then update it (this is the simplest way):**

```
x = MyMap.objects.get(name="dave")
x.cars = {"mini":"abc"}
x.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects

**You can also use `update()`:**

```
MyMap.objects.filter(name="dave").update(cars={"mini":"abc"})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update

**You can also use `update_or_create()`:**

```
x, created = MyMap.objects.update_or_create(name="dave", defaults={'cars': {"mini":"abc"}})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to update your model. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

```
obj, created = MyMap.objects.get_or_create(name="dave")
obj.cars = {"mini":"abc"}
obj.save()
```

This works for both create and update an object